# How to group columns only within in the scope of LISTAGG by excluding aggregation on other columns

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i have used below query to generate below report using listag

```
SELECT
  t1.ID,
  LISTAGG(t2.product, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t2.product) AS Purchased_Products
FROM
  Table1 t1
JOIN
  Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
GROUP BY
  t1.ID;
```

which produce below report

```
+----+----------------------+
| ID | Purchased_Products   |
+----+----------------------+
| 1  | laptop, phone        |
| 2  | book, headset         |
| 3  | iphone               |
+----+----------------------+
```

now i want to include columns from another table table3 with in the select statement but need to exclude in group by clause

```
+----+----------+-----+
| ID | address  | pin  |
+----+----------+------+
| 1  | bgr    |   432  |
| 2  | chennai|   434  |
| 3  | mumbai  |  445  |
+----+----------+------+
```

now i want to add address, pincode into the result without included in group by clause. ofcourse using join condition. thats clear.
however how to exclude  address,pin from group by clause while limiting t1.ID for LISTAGG within the select query?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: And what would be your expected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`listagg` is an aggregate function and requires **all** non-aggregated columns to be part of the `group by` clause.

Therefore, if you have to add column(s) from yet another table(s), you'll have to put newly added columns into `group by`, e.g.

```
select t1.id,
  listagg(t2.product, ', ') within group (order by t2.product) as purchased_products,
  t3.pin
from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
               join table3 t3 on t3.id = t1.id
group by t1.id, t3.pin;
```

---

Alternatively, if you used your current query as a subquery (or a CTE, as my example shows), then join it with another table, e.g.

```
with temp as
  (select t1.id,
     listagg(t2.product, ', ') within group (order by t2.product) as purchased_products
   from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
   group by t1.id
  )
select a.id, a.puchased_products,
  t3.pin
from temp a join table3 t3 on a.id = t3.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one record per ID in `table3` then you can use the aggregate function(`MIN` or `MAX`) on `ADDRESS` and `PIN` column as follows:

```
SELECT
  t1.ID,
  LISTAGG(t2.product, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t2.product) 
                  AS Purchased_Products,
  MAX(T3.ADDRESS) AS ADDRESS,
  MAX(T3.PIN)     AS PIN
FROM
  Table1 t1
  JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
  JOIN TABLE3 T3 ON T3.ID = T1.ID
GROUP BY t1.ID;
```